# Firebase 3.3 realtime database stuck to "Making a connection attempt" with React Native 0.32

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

**firebase@3.3.0**

**react-native v0.32** tested on android device with wifi

Firebase database doesn't have any auth rules, it's open read and write.

Given the following file structure :

```
|_ firebase.js
|_ actions.js
```

---

This doesn't work :

*firebase.js*

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

const config = {
    apiKey: "*****",
    authDomain: "****",
    databaseURL: "*****",
    storageBucket: "*****",
}

firebase.database.enableLogging(true);

export default firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

*actions.js*

```
import firebase from './firebase'

export const fetchData = () => {
    const Data = firebase.database().ref('some/data')
    Data.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log("snapshot", snapshot.val())  // never printed
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error)
    })
}
```

*debug output*

```
p:0: Browser went online.  
firebase-database.js:36 p:0: Listen called for /some/data default  
firebase-database.js:36 p:0: Making a connection attempt
```

Nothing else...

---

**This does work (but it's not a solution)** :

*firebase.js*

```
...same content as above...

export default () => firebase.initializeApp(config)  // we export a function instead to trigger the initialization when the app is ready
```

*actions.js*

```
...same content as above...
const Data = firebase().database().ref('some/data') // we "manually" trigger the initialization, it's obviously not a good solution since we can't initialize the app multiple times
```

*output*

```
p:0: Browser went online.  
firebase-database.js:36 p:0: Listen called for /some/data default  
firebase-database.js:36 p:0: Making a connection attempt  
firebase-database.js:36 p:0: Auth token refreshed  
firebase-database.js:36 getToken() completed. Creating connection. 
firebase-database.js:36 c:0:0: Connection created
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I also noticed that once I `import firebase from 'firebase'`, the `firebase` variable is available globally in all the files that is NOT the `firebase` var from the import statement (I could have written `import FooBar from 'firebase'`, the `firebase` global var is still imported)

Comment: Have you tried turn off debug mode? I had similar problem but it only happens in debug mode.

Comment: I actually did turned on the debug mode since nothing was happening, so unfortunately it's not that.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, something is broken between latest firebase and react-native (this might be normal but it doesn't seem documented anywhere). Worked for me with "firebase": "^3.1.0", "react": "15.2.1",    "react-native": "^0.29.0".

Comment: OK thanks ! Not sure where I should post the issue then...

Comment: @Pcriulan you could try different dependency combination to see which one breaks first. I had actually started to but npm caching issues made it take way too long for the time I could dedicate to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody seems to have an "official" answer. Here is the workaround I came with to provide some sort of lazy initialization :

**firebase.js**

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'

let _database = null

const initFirebase = () => {
    var config = {
        apiKey: "*************",
        authDomain: "************",
        databaseURL: "**********",
        storageBucket: "************",
    }

    Firebase.database.enableLogging(true)
    Firebase.initializeApp(config)
}

export const getDatabase = () => {
    if (!_database) {
        initFirebase()
        _database = Firebase.database()
    }
    return _database
}
```

Then, anywhere you need the `database`:

```
import { getDatabase } from './firebase'

const methodThatNeedDatabase = () => {
    getDatabase().ref('/some/ref')
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this actually make it faster or just defer the delay?